# Clojure Math/sqrt precision on big integers

Tags: java, math, clojure, sqrt

Why does the following Clojure code print "true"?

(please notice that the numbers differ in the last digit)

```
(== (Math/sqrt 10252519345963644753026N)
    (Math/sqrt 10252519345963644753025N))
```

Not sure whether this question is only about Clojure or if it also applies to other languages (Java's BigInteger?).

Printing them results in:

```
(str (Math/sqrt 10252519345963644753026N) " "
     (Math/sqrt 10252519345963644753025N))

1.01254725055E11 1.01254725055E11
```

Comment: Did you try to print the result of the sqrt operation on the two numbers separately?  Seems like they could lose enough precision to be equal as see at finite precision.

Comment: Math.sqrt uses double which only have 15 digits of precision. More digits than that can look the sample with `double` precision.

Comment: I don't know Clojure, but `Math/sqrt` is almost certainly converting its arguments to doubles before invoking the underling square root operation. As doubles, both the *input* values you give are identical (and therefore, of course, so are the outputs).

Comment: Printing is not necessarily a reliable way to inspect values (http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java `Math.sqrt` function

- takes a `double` argument and
- returns a `double`result.

As various comments suggest, the conversions that this induces lose the precision to distinguish between the numbers. In fact, conversion to `double` does so:

```
(= (double 10252519345963644753026N)
   (double 10252519345963644753025N))
;true
```

---

A `double` has a 53 bit precision. Since 10 bits is about 3 decimal digits, this is about 16 decimal digits precision. Your numbers are 23 digits long, so the last few digits are lost in conversion.